# The adaptive card showing again once I select the option in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am working on a chat bot and I have used adaptive cards in it.

When I select the option from an adaptive card, and click **Submit** I don't see its value but I get another adaptive card just below it.. See the image below:

[image]

What I am trying to do is, I am trying to show the selected value on user side as a reply to Bot's card, but when I select the value this card shows up again on click or on submit.

I have this code with me:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

    var activityReply = turnContext.Activity;
    if(turnContext.Activity.Value != null)
    {
        activityReply.Text = $"You chose: {turnContext.Activity.Value}";
    }

    // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);
}
```

And my Waterfall Step is like this:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> UIExperienceStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var cardAttachment = new Attachment();
    cardAttachment = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(); // this is the method where I am loading the adaptive card

    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("AdaptiveCardPrompt",
    new PromptOptions
    {
        Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
        {
            ContentType = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment().ContentType,
            Content = cardAttachment.Content
        }),
    }, cancellationToken);

}
```

**Please note:** I am using Bot Framework v4.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like your prompt might be reprompting, but you haven't told us what kind of prompt it is or given us any information that might help us help you, nor have you asked a question that indicates what you're trying to do. Consider linking to any tutorials or samples you're following and provide more relevant code.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, he thing I am getting the adaptive card from JSON. The UIExperienceStepAsync is a waterfall method. I am just trying to show the selected value. That is, when I select any option from that card, its value should be visible on User's end.

Comment: We can catch the User's response in OnMessageActivityAsync I know that. So what I want is when I select any value from card, it should display that selected value on User's end as a reply.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I have edited my question stating what I am expecting.

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question to include the code that constructs and adds your "AdaptiveCardPrompt" dialog.